# r plotting time series into graduated colours by groups using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data (results) looks like this:

```
1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9           10          subsites  sites
0.3207679   0.5831471   0.8062113   1.000211    1.17139     1.324008    1.461217    1.585459    1.698675    1.802433    1         1
0.5519985   0.9743214   1.3157794   1.600919    1.84415     2.054966    2.240087    2.40447     2.551864    2.68515     2         1
0.7527316   1.2980157   1.7215702   2.064576    2.350302    2.59345     2.803964    2.988854    3.153205    3.300787    3         1
0.9410568   1.5892921   2.0769323   2.463184    2.779815    3.046059    3.27444     3.473503    3.64928     3.806147    1         2
1.106054    1.834043    2.3672041   2.782478    3.119263    3.400492    3.640566    3.849008    4.032385    4.195388    2         2
1.262294    2.061886    2.6353753   3.0767      3.431931    3.72695     3.977544    4.19394     4.383119    4.550062    3         2
```

I would like to plot in graduated different colours, all subsites in each site, so site 1 for example would have subsite 1 dark blue, subsite 2, lighter blue, etc. Site 2 would have dark green for subsite 1 and lighter green for subsite 2 etc. I have tried to use     `reshape` and `ggplot2` but the graphs don't even take on the form I want and I can't figure out why.

I am trying to get a series of curved lines like this first image, but the output is much different (second graph).
[image: expected output]

[image: actual output]

Here's my code:

```
meltdf <- melt(results,id.vars=c("sites","subsites"), measure.vars=c(1:10), value.name="rawdata",variable.name="Days")
ggplot(meltdf,aes(x=Days,y=rawdata,colour=subsites,group=sites)) + geom_line()
```

Could someone please tell me how to melt my data so it generates the graph I need and how to make graduated colours within each group?
many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems close.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)    # for brewer.pal(...)

df <- cbind(id=1:nrow(df),df)
gg <- melt(df, id=c("id","subsites","sites"))
gg$variable=as.numeric(substr(gg$variable,2,4))
ggplot(gg)+
  geom_line(aes(x=variable,y=value ,color=factor(id)),size=1.5)+
  scale_color_manual("Site",values=c(rev(brewer.pal(3,"Blues")),
                                     rev(brewer.pal(3,"Greens"))), 
                     breaks=c(1,4), labels=unique(gg$sites))+
  labs(x="",y="")+
  theme_bw()
```

`df` is your data from the question (2 sites, 3 subsites).

The basic idea is to add an `id` column to your data.frame, then melt, then group on `id` using the color aesthetic. Now you have six colors. To make them blues for site 1 and greens for site 2 we use `scale_color_manual(...)` to create a custom list of color values using the Blues color palette for the first three, and the Greens color palette for the last three. Then we set the legend `breaks=c(1,4)` so that the legend displays the darkest Blue/Green. The palettes themselves come from [www.colorbrewer.org](http://www.colorbrewer.org), implemented in R in package `RColorBrewer`.

**Edit** [Response to OP's request in the comments.

With the complete (or more complete) dataset, this question illustrates two key principles:

1. With R, just about anything is possible.
2. Just because something is possible doesn't mean you should do it.

In essence OP has `response ~ time` data for 4 sites, where each site has between 7 and 10 subsites; so in total 36 time series. OP wishes to display these all on one plot, and hopes to distinguish them by having each site associated with a different base color (e.g. blue for site 1, green for site 2, etc.), and having the subsites distinguished by a color ramp in each color from dark to light. So, `(site 1, subsite 1)=dark blue`, `(site 1, subsite 10)=light blue`, etc.

To achieve this we need a generalized version of the approach above. Each curve gets its own color (so, 36 colors). We then create a manual color scale using 4 different ramps, each with the appropriate number of colors, in the right order. The code is below, again assuming OP's dataset is stored in a data.frame `df`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(colorRamps)

df <- read.csv("subset_for_dropbox.csv")
df <- cbind(id=1:nrow(df),df)
sites         <- aggregate(subsites~Sites,df,length)  # number of subsite for each site
sites$brks    <- c(1,1 + cumsum(sites$subsites)[1:(nrow(sites)-1)])
site.palettes <- c("Blues","Greens","Reds","Purples")
colors <- unlist(apply(sites,1,function(x){colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(9,site.palettes[x[1]]))[1:6])(x[2])}))
gg <- melt(df, id=c("id","subsites","Sites"))
gg$variable=as.numeric(substr(gg$variable,4,6))
# all curves on one plot
ggplot(gg)+
  geom_line(aes(x=variable,y=value ,color=factor(id)),size=1.5)+
  scale_color_manual("Site",values=colors, 
                     breaks=sites$brks, labels=unique(gg$Sites))+
  labs(x="",y="")+ xlim(0,10) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

It should be evident that this is not a good way to visualize the data. A better approach uses facets:

```
# faceted, color identifies site, color ramp identifies subsite
ggplot(gg)+
  geom_line(aes(x=variable,y=value ,color=factor(id)),size=1.5)+
  scale_color_manual("Site",values=colors, 
                     breaks=sites$brks, labels=unique(gg$Sites))+
  labs(x="",y="")+ xlim(0,10) +
  theme_bw()+
  facet_wrap(~Sites,nrow=1)
```

[image]

The problem with this plot is that you don't know which subsite goes with which color (is subsite 1 darkest, or subsite 10?). So a less colorful, but better approach uses facets to identify the sites, and the color ramp to identify the subsites:

```
# faceted, color ramp identifies subsite
ggplot(gg)+
  geom_line(aes(x=variable,y=value ,color=factor(subsites)),size=1.5)+
  scale_color_manual("subsite",values=colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(9,"Blues")[4:9]))(max(sites$subsites)))+
  labs(x="",y="")+ xlim(0,10) +
  theme_bw()+
  facet_wrap(~Sites,nrow=1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for this and for answering so quickly. I have a couple of questions. I am trying to adapt this to a much larger dataset: Can you please explain what the `gg$variable=as.numeric(substr(gg$variable,2,4))` line does? When I run it on my bigger dataset, it produces many NAs in this column before going to a string of 0s and 1s and 2s and 3s etc then back to NAs. I also have differing value lengths so can I use something like `length()` to set the number of colours?

Comment: The best thing would be to provide a link to your data. To answer directly: (1) When I read your sample data I get a data.frame with columns names `X1, X2, ... X10, sites, subsites`. So after `melt(...)` the column `gg$variable` has "X1", "X2", etc. The statement above strips the "X" and converts what's left to a numeric. Look at what's in 'gg` right after it's created. (2) The total number of colors is equal to the number of rows in your df, which in turn is the total combinations of sites and subsites.

Comment: Thank you, what I meant was I have different numbers of subsites at each site, when I enter different numbers for values=c(rev(brewer.pal(... I get the error message  'Error in data.frame(values = scale_map(scale, breaks), labels = I(scale_labels(scale)), : arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0'

Comment: In that case can you post a link to your data?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that, my data isn't online anywhere and there doesn't seem to be anywhere on stackoverflow to upload or embed files.

Comment: Can you put it on Dropbox?

Comment: can do, how do I get it to you? Thanks for all your help

Comment: Once you upload it you can generate a link in Dropbox. Post that link here. The link provides access to only that one file, not your whole Dropbox.

Comment: Thanks for spending so much time on this. All these options give me plenty of possibilities to view my data. Much appreciated.